# How to reference PreloadJS from my module after shimming?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, createjs, preloadjs

I was wondering if anyone knows how can I reference PreloadJS from a helper module I have created. My RequireJS configuration looks something like this:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: {
        preloadjs: '../bower_components/PreloadJS/lib/preloadjs-0.6.0.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'preloadjs': {
            exports:"createjs.PreloadJS"
        }
    }
});
```

And then, what I would like to do is to reference it from my helper module. Something like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'preloadjs'
], function ($, _) {

    var HelperModule = {

        doSomething: function () {
            // call preloadjs
        },

    };

    return HelperModule;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out I was having problems with the version of preloadjs I was using. Instead, I went ahead and used 0.4.1.

So this is my setup now:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: {
        preloadjs: '../bower_components/PreloadJS/lib/preloadjs-0.4.1.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'preloadjs': {
            exports:"createjs.LoadQueue"
        }
     }
});
```

And then this is how I reference it:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'preloadjs'
], function ($, _, PreloadJS) {

    var HelperModule = {

        doSomething: function () {
            var queue = new PreloadJS();
        }

    };

    return HelperModule;
```

});